# At what point does javascript allocate a memory slot for a variable(in OO context)?

Tags: javascript, object, memory, optimization, variable-assignment

I'm looking for a very specific answer to my question. The question is as per title, here's a sample case:

```
function MyObject(){
    this.value = null; //do we allocate a piece of memory of some sort
}
var meh = new MyObject();
```

I think I heard somewhere that JS doesn't allocate memory until assignment time, since it's weak-typed(and can't know how much memory to allocate), is that the case? Obviously it will allocate memory placeholder(pointer) for the newly created Object itself, but does it allocate memory for the *value* variable in this case?

The reason for this is that the Object I actually have in mind has multiple variables/arrays/hashtables (which I do eventually assign/populate), so I was hoping to gain some performance benefits by declaring all the (persistent)object variables up top(to help out JS engine with memory alloc, much like c/c++ code optimizations at compile time), as I'm working in a very constrained JS runtime.

Like I said, I'm looking for a very specific answer(I have googled/searched for it) as a seasoned Javascript/c++ developer. I'm familiar with the "let javascript engine worry about all that" philosophy and that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Where you declare variables is irrelevant to memory allocation since all declarations in an execution context are processed before any code is executed, even if the declaration statement includes assignment.

Comment: How memory allocation really works would depend on the engine. The specification does not dictate anything in this direction.

Comment: Guess it's a "let js-engine worry about that" case after all haha. Thanks guys.

Comment: Very interesting question. Did you find an answer to this?